# Copy paste data from Excel to grid using JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid

this is my first time use of JQGrid, I want to copy data from excel and paste it into grid using jQGrid. I thought to create a textarea to paste excel data which act like a clipboard and then this data will display in grid, but I don't have any idea how to do that also I searched for two days, but I can't find the solution using JQGrid.

Any help is appreciated :)